# How to complete the following task in django orm

Tags: django, orm

I have two models. one is Author and the other is Book. an author can have multiple books. so the id of the author is the foreign key. and I have the following data.

Author Table

| id | Author Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom |

Books Table

| id | Author | Book Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | rescue a person |
| 2 | 1 | be a doctor |

I want to create a function to get the following result when I query the author record.

| id | author name | books name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | **rescue a person, be a doctor** |

Answer (score 2):

for one2many and M2M, `prefetch_related` is used:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
author = Author.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related(Prefetch('book_set',to_attr='books'))
```

now, the `author[0].books` gives the books of the author. [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid subsequent queries when iterating over your queryset, @Amin Mir answer is sufficient.
If you need data to be aggregated inside of your queryset, you should take a look at:

- ArrayAgg for Postgres: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg
- GroupConcat for MySQL and MariaDB:
  https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat

The GroupConcat doc example should help you with the syntax

Comment: Yes. it can be done. thanks. is there another solution? because I want to use the native method as much as possible.

Comment: @user571102 the proposed solution is a native django function, what do you mean by "native" ?

Comment: Those are natives. But at the end of the day Django depends on the DB you're using and those might not offer the same functionalities

Comment: Because my project uses MySql and GroupConcat is a function of the Django-Mysql package for the extension of the Django model.  If I use the package, I think I need to reconstruct the Model. I don't have such experience. Could you give me more information about it? Thanks.